# Error (CS0501): 'Script_Instance.myComponents.oPoints()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (line 101)

Tags: c#

In c# in grasshopper, I defined a list and add the data(points) inside this list, but the data is not available in this list.

```
 private void RunScript(List<Point3d> iPoints, Point3d iTarget, ref object A)
  {


    myComponents.Target = iTarget;

    myComponents.oPoints = iPoints;



...

    A = oPoints;
  }


  public class myComponents

  {
    public static List<Point3d> oPoints(); //this is where the coding is wrong

...


  }
```

I expect in oPoints list there would be the points from iPoints, but there is nothing, and the error message is:
Error (CS0501): 'Script_Instance.myComponents.oPoints()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (line 101)

Comment: `public static List oPoints();` The error means exactly what it says. You've defined a method but not told the compiler what the method **does**. Based on your earlier code, I _suspect_ you meant to use `public List<sometypehere> oPoints {get; set;}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you intended to define a method you'd have to declare a body:

```
public static List oPoints()
{
    //Body
}
```

If you intended to define a field you need to remove the ().

```
public static List oPoints;
```